# How does "accept all assets" federated address in Lobstr work?

Tags: trustline

in the web interface for lobstr, they tell to to use this federated address for receiving any asset, even if you don't have a trustline.

I thought that's impossible.  How is that done? I thought I had to have a trustline first to be able to accept the asset? Are they using some sort of proxy account which has all trustlines to accept the asset for you? and then maybe their app then buys the trustline and it moves it as a second step?

in my case, stk@token.io*lobstr.co is the "accept all" federated address.

you'll see it lists all the stellar assets that can be sent.

feel free to send me any assets if you want to test this :)

Answer (score 4):

Steve, just sent you 1 SLVR (1 gram of silver) to your accept all address.

Receiving an asset without a trustline is not possible on the network level.

However, when you make a payment to accept all address, the funds are actually sent to [this](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GBEUDKANIFPTFHPWJ5T3R6RIO36RQBFGHYPAQ6STH7KMNDHAT36LHOLD) escrow account, which has most of the trustline already configured (and keeps adding them automatically).

The intended recipient will then receive a notification and will need to claim the assets.

LOBSTR app will show a claim option like this:

[image: claim pop-up]

Accepting the incoming payment, will add trustline and initiate the payment from escrow account to the account of the user.

Some additional things:

1. We refund unclaimed funds after 30 days automatically to the sender.
2. To prevent spam and ensure a user has enough funds to accept a trustline, we require the payment through accept all address to be valued at least 0.5 XLM (on SDEX). Smaller payments are refunded immediately.
3. Worth pointing out that it's interoperable. As in you don't need LOBSTR to make the payment, it's just a regular payment to federated address, and works from most of the Stellar wallets.
4. If the user needs a trustline opened to accept incoming payment, we will also sell some of the sent assets to fund the trustline - so a person would receive 0.5 XLM (for the trustline) and the remaining part of the payment. *Example: sending 1 SLVR to a person without SLVR trustline will get him 0.85 SLVR and 0.5 XLM (if 0.5 XLM=0.15 SLVR).*
5. This can be used to send assets to people without a Stellar account. You could send SLVR to elon@tesla.com*lobstr.co. Elon would receive an email to sign up and claim the funds.

Answer (score 1):

Per Tomer: They escrow the asset for you and let you pull it once you establish a trustline